# IBM MQ container failed to start

Tags: docker, ibm-mq

I have an error when starting the IBM MQ Container. 
I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/mq-connect-to-queue-manager/#docker)

After the docker run:

```
docker run --name mq-demo --env LICENSE=accept --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 --volume qm1data:/mnt/mqm --publish 1414:1414 --publish 9443:9443 --network mq-demo-network --network-alias qmgr --detach --env MQ_APP_PASSWORD=mypassw0rd ibmcom/mq:latest
```

The container exited with this error:

```
> docker logs mq-demo 
2020-01-21T14:34:37.059Z CPU architecture: amd64
2020-01-21T14:34:37.059Z Linux kernel version: 4.15.0-74-generic
2020-01-21T14:34:37.059Z Container runtime: docker
2020-01-21T14:34:37.059Z Base image: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.1 (Ootpa)
2020-01-21T14:34:37.061Z Running as user ID 888 () with primary group 888, and supplementary groups 0
2020-01-21T14:34:37.061Z Capabilities (bounding set): chown,dac_override,fowner,fsetid,kill,setgid,setuid,setpcap,net_bind_service,net_raw,sys_chroot,mknod,audit_write,setfcap
2020-01-21T14:34:37.061Z seccomp enforcing mode: filtering
2020-01-21T14:34:37.061Z Process security attributes: docker-default (enforce)
2020-01-21T14:34:37.061Z Detected 'ext4' volume mounted to /mnt/mqm
2020-01-21T14:34:37.062Z Error setting admin password: exit status 1: [115 117 100 111 58 32 101 102 102 101 99 116 105 118 101 32 117 105 100 32 105 115 32 110 111 116 32 48 44 32 105 115 32 47 117 115 114 47 98 105 110 47 115 117 100 111 32 111 110 32 97 32 102 105 108 101 32 115 121 115 116 101 109 32 119 105 116 104 32 116 104 101 32 39 110 111 115 117 105 100 39 32 111 112 116 105 111 110 32 115 101 116 32 111 114 32 97 110 32 78 70 83 32 102 105 108 101 32 115 121 115 116 101 109 32 119 105 116 104 111 117 116 32 114 111 111 116 32 112 114 105 118 105 108 101 103 101 115 63 10]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can try a different password :)

Comment: The question is that I didn't even set the admin password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue with the help of [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546822/why-does-sudo-fail-inside-docker-complaining-about-nosuid)

It was due to the `sudo` failure in the container. I removed the `nosuid` from the file system on which the container was mounted and it runs ok.

```
sudo mount -n -o remount,suid /mount/for/var/lib/docker
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried that command and have not seen that error!. This is the modified command from me:

```
docker run --name mq-demo --env LICENSE=accept --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 --publish 1414:1414 --publish 9443:9443 --detach --env MQ_APP_PASSWORD=mypassw0rd docker.io/ibmcom/mq:latest
```

Only difference is to use fully qualified name for the image in command. You could try that and you may also want to clean up any existing ibmcom/mq images first and try this command.

Comment: Thank you. It was due to another reason. I've posted it below.